# Propósito do nome de uma chave estrangeira

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, pgadmin, administração-postgresql

Estou criando tabelas para um sistema que estou desenvolvendo e ao entrar na parte de adicionar chave estrangeira pela interface do `PostgreSQL 9.3.17` reparei que tem o campo `nome` para identificar essa chave, nunca dei muita atenção a isto e sempre coloquei o nome da chave com o mesmo nome da coluna da tabela.

A tela da adição com o input nome é assim:

[image: Imagem ilustrando adição de chave estrangeira]

No momento que uma chave é adicionada o nome dela é exibido dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Qual o intuito do nome da chave estrangeira?
- O que pode acarretar no futuro ao negligenciar o uso deste nome?

Answer (score 0):

- Qual o intuito do nome da chave estrangeira?

O intuitivo do nome da chave estrangeira, é facilitar o entendimento das relações com outras tabelas.

- O que pode acarretar no futuro ao negligenciar o uso deste nome?

Não acontecem muitos problemas ao negligenciar o uso deste nome, claro, é uma boa prática sempre utilizar nomes que facilitem o entendimento da relação com outras tabela. Para facilitar o entendimento de outro DBA que poderá vir a fazer manutenção após você, imagine só um exemplo.
Você criar varias relações com tabela de endereços, pedidos, e clientes, e coloca o nome da chave estrangeira como ck, pk, te. Claro que é um uso inadequado do nome da chave estrangeira.

Comment: Você me respondeu qual o intuito da existência de uma chave estrangeira, mas a minha pergunta foi qual o intuito do NOME dela.

Comment: O mesmo ocorre pra segunda pergunta, a questão não é a estrutura do banco com a utilização ou não das chaves, e sim a utilização ou não de forma correta/devida dos NOMES das chaves.

Comment: Irei corrigir..